# neo4j cypher {id: 123} or c.id = 123 performance comparison

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any difference in Neo4j from the performance point of view when we are using a following Cypher expressions:

```
(:Characteristics {id: 123})
```

or

```
(c:Characteristics) WHERE c.id = 123
```

or both of them are equal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal. The top example is just syntactical sugar, they'll both produce the same plan.